# What is the correct way to obtain a specialized child class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a particular issue where I have a general `class Command` I am using to represent commands in a buffer in sequence. I also have several child classes of it, like `ComputeCommand`, `DefineCommand`, `DisplayCommand`, etc.
 The constructor for each subclass takes a `String` argument, which the command parses according to the command syntax, which varies from command type to command type.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
String [] lines = { ... };
ArrayList<Command> commands = new ArrayList<Command>();
for(String line: lines){
    commands.add(new Command(line))
}
```

However, I need the more specialized classes to be able to process each command.

If I could define the constructor something like:

```
Command(String line){
    if(ComputeCommand.isValidComputeCommand(line))
        return new ComputeCommand(line);
    else if(DisplayCommand.isValidDisplayCommand(line))
        return new DisplayCommand(line);
    [ ... ]
}
```

That would accomplish what I need, but constructors don't work that way, as we all know.

One way I have thought of is to include a method like

```
static Command getInstance(String line){ [...] }
```

to perform that function, however I am not sure that that is the correct approach in this situation.

Another possible way is to create factory classes for each one:

```
class CommandFactory(){
    CommandFactory [] subFactories = {new ComputeCommandFactory(), [...]};
    Command makeCommand(String line){
        for(CommandFactory subFactory: subFactories)
            if(subFactory.canMake(String line))
                return subFactory.makeCommand(line);
    }
    boolean canMake(String line){
        for(CommandFactory subFactory: subFactories)
            if(subFactory.canMake(String line))
                return true;
    }
}
```

I think this may be the most oop-correct way to do this, but I don't want to add the extra complexity if there is a better way.

What is the correct design pattern to use in this situation?

EDIT:
I also plan to subclass some of the commands further, for instance the `ComputeCommand` could have an `AddCommand` or a `MultiplyCommand` subclass.

Comment: Just a note: `static Command getInstance(String line){ [...] }` is _already_ a factory method.  You don't have to introduce a new class just to have a factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you thought, your `CommandFactory` approach is the closest to correct. Factories / factory methods are usually used for this kind of problem.

The only issue you obviously see is that this `CommandFactory` has to know about all the subfactories, has to know about all the types. This means that if you add a new type, you'll have to add it to the `CommandFactory`, too.

But! You can use e.g. the [`ClassFinder`](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/classutil/ClassFinder.html) from the [`org.clapper.util`](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/) library to find all classes implementing `Command` or extending `CommandFactory` in your classpath. This way, you can add any new `Commands` in the future and the `CommandFactory` will still find them and add them to `subFactories`.

You can also reverse the problem - let the subfactories (or the individual `Commands` themselves) know about the factory! First find them with `ClassFinder`, then call a method on them that will add them to the factory list. It's similar approach to how listeners work.

Answer (score 1):

What I am reading is that you want to build the correct object based off of context? You have some string, and you want to build the correct object from the contents of that string?

You could have a CommandBuilder/Factory, and that's where you can place your if-else logic to return the right command.

```
public Command buildCommand(String line){
    if(ComputeCommand.isValidComputeCommand(line))
        return computeCommandFactory.buildCommand(line);
    else if(DisplayCommand.isValidDisplayCommand(line))
        return displayCommandFactory.buildCommand(line);
    [ ... ]

}
```

It sounds like you want to use a builder or an [abstract factory](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html) to build the Command objects you require. When you have a large if-else if chain, you generally want to use a strategy pattern.

Comment: The poster should also consider using a lexer and parser such as ANTLR or JavaCC rather than trying to handle all the decision making in each command class.  I've never used either, though I have worked with lex/yacc back when I programmed in C, C++, and Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a combination of `Factory` and `Chain of Responsibility` patterns to do what you want.

```
interface CommandFactory{
    Command create(String line);

    void addToChain(CommandFactory next);
}
```

If your factory can't handle the given line, then it passes the line to the next factory in the chain:

```
class ComputeCommandFactory{


    CommandFactory next;

    Command create(String line){
        if(<can process>){
           return new ComputeCommand(line);
        }
        if(next ==null){
          throw Exception("can't process");
        }
        return next.create(line);
     }

 }
```

This way you can add new factories later (even at runtime).  This is similar to how adding classloaders and Database Drivers work in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. The pattern you are looking to work with here is the Factory Pattern.
Your thinking is right, and patterns are nothing but such thinkings that have been "written" down on a paper :).

So, for your case, you can do something like this:

```
public class CommandFactory
{
   public static Command getCommand (String line)
   {
      Command command = null;
      if (ComputeCommand.isValidComputeCommand (line))
      {
        command = new ComputeCommand (line);
      }
      else if (DisplayCommand.isValidDisplayCommand (line))
      {
        command = new DisplayCommand (line);
      }

     return command;
   }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Command command = CommandFactory.getCommand (line);
```

Hope that helps.